# Cron job setting,explanation

Tags: unix, cron

For cron job setting,I defined a job as below:

```
 * */12 * *
```

What I had assumed that it means the cron job will run after every 12 hours,unfortunately found that its running more frequently,not sure how frequently but the output was large than expected.

Can any explain it simply,I went through different docs but it seems there are several way to set a single cron.

Can anyone explain it easily?

Btw I updated my cron for running every 12 hours like below:

```
* * 12 * * ?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This line should run at **12AM** and **12PM**:

`* 0,12 * * * /path/to/command`

Answer (score 0):

`* */12 * *` means run every minutes on 0 and 12. If you want to make it run once in those hours, put a number instead of the first star(*), such as

```
20 */12 * *
```

By the way, there should be 5 time fields in the cron job instead of 4 fields, so it should actually be

```
20 */12 * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same and I found [this](http://cronchecker.net/) site very useful.
It will explain your cron job.

look at the below example:

1. ***/15 * * * * cd ~/ecg;**

Explanation: **The command *cd ~/ecg;* will execute every 15 minutes of every hour on every day of every month.**

1. **15 09 07 03 * php abc.php**

Explanation: **The command *php abc.php* will execute at 9:15am on the 7th of March.**